# how to send variable form javascript to php?

Tags: php, javascript

how can i send variable from java script function and use it for a function of PHP?

```
enter code here
<script>
    function showpopup(var1){
        document.getElementById('popup').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('mane').value=var1;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Generally with a POST or GET

Comment: here is an old thread ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php

Comment: From javascript to PHP. Probably with Ajax. I don't really see a variable in the code (maybe var1)?

Comment: generate a string like this and prepare the php page... youwebsite.com/yourpage.php?var=var1

Comment: and what variable you want to post? And to which PHP script? and how do you want to send it? and what input are you going to provide? and what output do you expect? exuberance redefined :p

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is generally accepted as impossible as `JavaScript` is **client side** and `PHP` is **Server Side**

That said, if you need some `PHP` to run **after** the page has already loaded, then you'll be looking at needing something like [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP) or jQuery's [.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
.  Look into those, and you'll be able find what you need.